# Pass a pointer to a function as read-only in C

Tags: c, function, pointers, readonly

Just as the title says, can I pass a pointer to a function so it's only a copy of the pointer's contents?
I have to be sure the function doesn't edit the contents.

Thank you very much.

Comment: After 8 years, I realize how dumb and pointless this question is. A pointer is a reference to data, so the only way to do so is to copy the data, there's nothing like a read-only memory permission (unless it's the part holding the executable itself).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have to be sure the function doesn't edit the contents

Unless the function takes a `const` parameter, the only thing you can do is explicitly pass it a copy of your data, perhaps created using `memcpy`.

Comment: Even if you use (const int *ptr) as parameter you can still change the value being pointed to (by creating a second pointer inside the function, for instance). The only way to be 100% sure it won't change is to pass a copy of the value indeed. Right?

Comment: @DanielS If it creates a non-const pointer and makes it point to the contents of the const pointer it's stepping into undefined-behavior land. I.e. it's invalid code.

Comment: I can't use const, I just want to make sure the function uses a copy of the contents passed via pointer. The memcpy looks like the best solution, can you show me the syntax, please?

Comment: @HaskellElephant I don't understand what you mean. Care to expand ? I see many examples in the answer you indicated but I stand by my answer: if the function doesn't guarantee it - using `const` the right way or in documentation - the only way to be sure is to pass a copy.

Answer (score 7):

Yes,

```
void function(int* const ptr){
    int i;
    //  ptr = &i  wrong expression, will generate error ptr is constant;
    i = *ptr;  // will not error as ptr is read only  
    //*ptr=10;  is correct 

}

int main(){ 
    int i=0; 
    int *ptr =&i;
    function(ptr);

}
```

In `void function(int* const ptr)` ptr is constant but what ptr is pointing is not constant hence `*ptr=10` is correct expression!

---

```
void Foo( int       *       ptr,
          int const *       ptrToConst,
          int       * const constPtr,
          int const * const constPtrToConst )
{
    *ptr = 0; // OK: modifies the "pointee" data
    ptr  = 0; // OK: modifies the pointer

    *ptrToConst = 0; // Error! Cannot modify the "pointee" data
    ptrToConst  = 0; // OK: modifies the pointer

    *constPtr = 0; // OK: modifies the "pointee" data
    constPtr  = 0; // Error! Cannot modify the pointer

    *constPtrToConst = 0; // Error! Cannot modify the "pointee" data
    constPtrToConst  = 0; // Error! Cannot modify the pointer
}
```

[Learn here!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Const-correctness)

Comment: "In void function(const int* ptr) ptr is constant but what its pointing is not constant. hence *ptr=10 in void function(const int* ptr) is a valid expression." I don't think this is right. *ptr is read only in this case, so you can't attribute to it.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `const`

`void foo(const char * pc)`

here `pc` is pointer to const char and by using `pc` you can't edit the contents.

But it doesn't guarantee that you can't change the contents, because by creating  another pointer to same content you can modify the contents.

So,It's up to you , how are you going to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

> I have to be sure the function doesn't edit the contents.

What contents? The value pointed to by the pointer? In this case, you can declare your function like

```
void function(const int *ptr);
```

then `function()` cannot change the integer pointed to by ptr.

If you just want to make sure `ptr` itself is not changed, don't worry: it's passed by value (as everything in C), so even if the function changes its `ptr` parameter, that won't affect the pointer that was passed in.

Comment: Even if you declare the way you did the function can still change the value pointed by ptr. One could create a second pointer inside the function, for instance, attribute to it the memory address on ptr, and then change the value there.

Comment: @DanielS Well, if you have `void func(const int *ptr)` function, then writing `*(int *)ptr = 42;` is undefined behavior, so you're wrong.